# Zsh compdef for apt-get install, or other 2 part commands

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

How can I use a compdef for zsh completion such that a custom written function uses a 2 part command for the completion?

Example:

```
my_function () {
    sudo apt-get install $@
}

compdef my_function=<WHAT GOES HERE?>
compdef my_function=apt-get install # DOESN'T WORK
compdef my_function='apt-get install' # ALSO NO
```

Any and all help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As much as you may be reluctant to do so try with bare zsh -- remember seeing issues on omz github page to that ( as i remember still not fixed)

Comment: There is nothing above that isn't "bare zsh". The autocompletion from omz does not interfere as far as I'm aware.

Comment: then you need to read their github page OR visit #zsh on freenode, oh my zsh is some of the worst managed and oldest zsh code around ---coming from another zsh user btw.